# Fresh install of Trellis by Roots on Ubuntu & VituralBox is missing composer.json under /srv/www/website.com/current

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, composer-php, vagrant, trellis

This is the error message I got when I first run 'vagrant provision' (after command 'vagrant up' blocked in 'Mounting NFS shared folders...') under the trellis directory:

```
TASK [wordpress-install : Install Dependencies with Composer] ******************
System info:
Ansible 2.9.11; Vagrant 2.2.9; Linux
Trellis version (per changelog): "Removes ID from Lets Encrypt bundled certificate and make filename stable"
---------------------------------------------------
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file 
  as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" 
  section failed: [default] (item=example.com) => 
{
  "ansible_loop_var": "item",
  "changed": false,
  "item": {
    "key": "example.com",
    "value": {
      "admin_email": "admin@example.test",
      "cache": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "local_path": "../site",
      "multisite": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "site_hosts": [
        {
          "canonical": "example.test",
          "redirects": [
            "www.example.test"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "ssl": {
        "enabled": false,
        "provider": "self-signed"
      }
    }
  },
  "stdout": "Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current\nTo initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ \"Getting Started\" section\n",
  "stdout_lines": [
    "Composer could not find a composer.json file in /srv/www/example.com/current",
    "To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ \"Getting Started\" section"
  ]
} 
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

default                    : ok=125  changed=83   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=34   rescued=0    ignored=0

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.

How do I fix this? Where to find the right **composer.json** for Trellis, Bedrock, and Sage for local development on Linux?

Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I have no clue what all these libraries are used for, but if there is no `composer.json`, it's pretty obvious that you cannot run `composer install`

Comment: this is the error i got when i run vagrant up.
i found solution with OSx Catalina in https://blog.docksal.io/nfs-access-issues-on-macos-10-15-catalina-75cd23606913 but i can't find a solution for Ubuntu